# Consulta Compilación SASS con NPM en Servidor

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, linux, sass

Con un amigo, discutiendo sobre la implementación de una aplicación web que hicimos en PHP Laravel 5.6, surgió un tema para investigar y aprender sobre SASS y NPM: ¿Se debería compilar el código para producción en el servidor (**Caso A**), o en el ambiente local donde estamos trabajando (**Caso B**)?

Para empezar, a compilar me refiero a llamar al comando `npm run prod`.

Esta aplicación que "creamos" se instala manualmente en cada cliente, para luego configurarlo y adaptarlo.

En el **Caso A**, usualmente hablamos de un servidor (VPS) con S.O. Ubuntu y Plesk Onyx 17 que contratamos en un proveedor de alojamiento web.

En el **Caso B**, usualemnte hablamos de un ordenador de escritorio o laptop con S.O. Windows y XAMPP

> En ambos casos ejecutamos `npm run prod` en el directorio de la aplicación designado a cada cliente.

¿Qué sería lo más conveniente? ¿Compilar en el servidor o localmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas simple y correcto seria compilar en local para obtener los archivos estáticos (CSS, JavaScript, fuentes e imágenes) listos para producción.

Ya que para una aplicación en Laravel que no dependa de librerías JavaScript para el servidor es innecesario instalar nodejs y npm en producción.

[Compiling Assets (Laravel Mix)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix)